# Is it possible to execute a CloudFormation file in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, terraform

One team has already written a cloudformation template as a `.yml` file that provisions a stack of resources.

Is it possible to leverage this file by executing it from within Terraform? Or does it have to be rewritten?

I'm new to terraform and just getting started.

If I were using the AWS CLI I would execute a command like this,

```
aws cloudformation create-stack  --stack-name my-new-stack  --template-body file://mystack.yml --parameters ParameterKey=AmiId
```

I'd like to include the equivalent of this command in my terraform configuration.

If it is possible and you can point me to an example, I would really appreciate that.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid you have to rewrite it, I don't think what you ask is possible.

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudformation_stack.html#template_url

Comment: If you are having trouble reading the yml file, try upgrading your version of terraform. I saw today that it does not work in .7.7 but can confirm it works in .9.3

Answer (score 58, accepted):

[The `aws_cloudformation_stack` resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudformation_stack) serves as a bridge from Terraform into CloudFormation, which can be used either as an aid for migration from CloudFormation to Terraform (as you're apparently doing here) or to make use of some of CloudFormation's features that Terraform doesn't currently handle, such as rolling deployments of new instances into an [ASG](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/AutoScalingGroup.html).

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "example" {
  name = "example"
  parameters = {
    VpcId = var.vpc_id
  }
  template_body = file("${path.module}/example.yml")
}
```

The `parameters` argument allows passing data from Terraform into the Cloudformation stack. It's also possible to use the `outputs` attribute to make use of the *results* of the CloudFormation stack elsewhere in Terraform, for a two-way integration:

```
resource "aws_route_53_record" "example" {
  name = "service.example.com"
  type = "CNAME"
  ttl  = 300

  records = [
    aws_cloudformation_stack.example.outputs["ElbHostname"],
  ]
}
```

---

If you have a pre-existing CloudFormation stack that *isn't* managed by Terraform, you can still make use of its outputs using [the `aws_cloudformation_stack` *data source*](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/cloudformation_stack):

```
data "aws_cloudformation_stack" "example" {
  name = "example"
}

resource "aws_route_53_record" "example" {
  name = "service.example.com"
  type = "CNAME"
  ttl  = 300

  records = [
    data.aws_cloudformation_stack.example.outputs["ElbHostname"],
  ]
}
```

---

These features together allow you to effectively mix CloudFormation and Terraform in a single system in different combinations, whether it's as a temporary measure while migrating or permanently in situations where a hybrid solution is desired.

Comment: do we define stack policies in here as well?

Answer (score 7):

I can confirm that template_body with a file reference to a cloudformation template works. I assume template_url will also work great.
Example

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "my-new-stack" {
  name = "my-new-stack"
  parameters {
    Name="my-new-stack"
    Port="22"
    VpcId = "${var.vpc_id}"
  }
  template_body = "${file("${path.module}/mystack.yml")}"
}
```