# Problem passing parameters created in Terraform to CloudFormation

Tags: parameter-passing, terraform, aws-cloudformation, terraform-provider-aws

With guidance from a [previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43266506/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-cloudformation-file-in-terraform), I am trying to pass two parameters created in my Terraform template into a CloudFormation template as parameters:

My Terraform (0.13.5) code:

```
    resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "cloudwatch-synthetics-canary" {
      provider = aws.primary
      name          = "cloudwatch-synthetics"
      parameters = {
        CloudWatchSyntheticsRole = aws_iam_role.cloudwatch_synthetics_role.arn,
        ResultsBucket = aws_s3_bucket.results_bucket.arn
      }
      template_body = file("${path.module}/cloudwatch_canary.yml")
    }

resource "aws_iam_role" "cloudwatch_synthetics_role" {
  provider           = aws.primary
  name               = "CloudWatchSyntheticsRole"
  description        = "Allows Cloudwatch Lambda to operate in this account."
  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowLambdaAssumeRole",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "cloudwatch_synthetics_role_policy" {
  provider    = aws.primary
  name        = "CloudWatchSyntheticsRolePolicy"
  path        = "/"
  description = "Addtional allowances for the synthetics role"

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [

    # --- SNIPPED FOR BREVITY ---

  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "cloudwatch_synthetics_role_policy_attachment" {
  provider = aws.primary
  role       = aws_iam_role.cloudwatch_synthetics_role.name
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.cloudwatch_synthetics_role_policy.arn
}
```

My CloudFormation code:

```
Parameters:
  CanaryName:
    Type: String
    Default: my-canary
    MaxLength: 21
  HostName:
    Type: String
    Default: api.myhost.net
    MaxLength: 128
  Path:
    Type: String
    Default: /v1/status
    MaxLength: 256
  Port:
    Type: Number
    Default: 443
  CloudWatchSyntheticsRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  ResultsBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
...

Resources:
   ExecutionRoleArn:
      Fn::GetAtt:
         - CloudWatchSyntheticsRole
         - Arn             # <-- TRIED WITH AND WITHOUT THIS
```

In Terraform.io, the error is as follows:

```
Error: Creating CloudFormation stack failed: ValidationError: Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource CloudWatchSyntheticsRole
    status code: 400, request id: 694c...
```

I tried making the types in the CFT as Strings, but that didn't seem to work, either. The Fn::GetAtt: also had '- Arn' below the CloudwatchSyntheticsRole to refer to the Arn, but since I'm passing that in directly, I tried removing it.

I feel like I'm close, but missing something and just need some help from some fresh eyes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the solution, found by a co-worker of mine is pretty simple:

1. Make sure ALL CFT variables are in Terraform and pass any default values through Terraform as literals to Cloudformation
2. *Remove* all default parameters from CloudFormation, but still keep the Name and Type of variable at a minimum. Other constraints like 'MaxLength' are ok, too.

Example:

Terraform.tf:

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "cloudwatch-synthetics-canary" {
  provider = aws.primary
  name          = "cloudwatch-synthetics"
  parameters = {
    CanaryName = "my-canary",
    HostName = "api.server.net",
    Path = "/v1/status",
    Port = 443,
    RoleArn = aws_iam_role.cloudwatch_synthetics_role.arn,
    S3Location = "s3://${aws_s3_bucket.results_bucket.id}"
  }
  template_body = file("${path.module}/cloudwatch_canary.yml")
}
```

Cloudformation.yml:

```
Parameters:
  CanaryName:
    Type: String
    MaxLength: 21
  HostName:
    Type: String
    MaxLength: 128
  Path:
    Type: String
    MaxLength: 256
  Port:
    Type: Number
  RoleArn:
    Type: String
  S3Location:
    Type: String
    MaxLength: 1024
```